# Access Data From Pivot Table On Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to get data from a pivot table.

I have 2 models: **sites**, **technologies**. These 2 models are related by a pivot table called **site_technology**, this table has 2 columns called *col_a*, *col_b* that I would like to access. Right now I have this:

```
class Site{
  public function technologies(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Technology')
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I link the 2 models, and how do I access the data on that piovt table with eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this question a lot, the best way I have found to do this is with the following code.

```
class Site{
  public function technologies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Technology::class, 'PIVOT_TABLE')->withPivot('column_a', 'column_b')
  }
}
```

This will allow you to get the data by doing this.

```
$data = Site::first()->technologies->first()->pivot->column_b
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Comment: @BabyJebus you can accept the answer if it worked for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers